# Why does my function not require me to use strings when I want to return something when it is true?

Tags: python-3.x

Why does my function not require me to use strings when I want to return something when it is true? Most of the time when I try to create a function, it requires me to place a string in the return portion, however, this problem does not. I apologize in advance if I am not describing this correctly.

for example:
why does this function not need strings?

```
def myfunc(x,y,z):
    if z == True:
        return x
    elif z == False:
        return y
```

but this function does?

```
def myfunc(x,y,z):
    if z == True:
        return 'Hello'
    elif z == False:
        return 'Goodbye'
```

Comment: return type is doesn't matter in python, you can return a string, number, boolean, object or anything that you want. Although it is a bad practice to leave parameters unused in a function like in example 2, if your functions do not require the parameter, make sure you remove them completely to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think x and y are not strings?

Have you considered whether the program is aware of whether x and y will be strings when the program is run?

In fact, in Python functions will *always* return a value (an object). If you do not specify what the return value is, then the return value is `None`.

This is a valid function (bad, but valid):

```
def myfunc(x,y,z):
    if z == True:
        pass
    elif z == False:
        pass
```

This function will always return `None`, which is not a string.

Likewise, this is also valid, and will always return `None`, and not a string.

```
def myfunc(x,y,z):
    pass
```